# Oracle query order by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi i have this  data on my DOMP_LOG_EVENT table

```
DOCID                        DOC_VERSION    CN_NO   SEQ USERID  EVENT_DESC  DATE_LOG    REMARKS UPLOAD_DATE

7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0           0   PHG01096    Document created                7/7/2020 8:44:36 AM     
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0.01        0   PHG01096    Document Submitted for Review   7/7/2020 8:45:30 AM     
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0.01        0   PHG00583    Document reviewed              7/7/2020 8:46:19 AM      
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0.01        0   DOMSYS 3.0  Document Submitted for Approval 7/7/2020 8:46:19 AM     
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0.01        0   NXP16848    Document Approved              7/7/2020 8:47:18 AM      
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0.01        0   PHG01925    Document Approved             7/7/2020 8:48:09 AM       
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0.01        0   DOMSYS 3.0  Document Submitted for Publication  7/7/2020 8:48:09 AM     
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0.01        0   NXP74045    Document Published             7/7/2020 8:49:04 AM      
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0           0   PHG01096    Document Deployed             7/7/2020 8:50:33 AM       
7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8    0           1   DOMSYS 3.0  Document Submitted for Deployment   7/7/2020 8:50:33 AM
```

i want to achive like this query result

[image: Goal result]

`Document Submitted for Deployment` should go first before `Document Deployed`

Here's my current query

```
Select doc_version, date_log, event_desc, userid, nvl(fullname,userid) as fullname from domp_log_event A, dom_appusers b
 where a.userid = b.username(+) and round(doc_version) = '0' and docid ='7a32bf6024264a109ce32d05c52d70f8' order by docid, date_log,userid DESC, seq  ,doc_version
```

How can i achive it without changing data on the table

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the sample data again and I think following `ORDER BY` will work:

```
 ORDER BY DOCID,
          DOC_VERSION DESC,
          DATE_LOG,
          DECODE(EVENT_DESC,'Document Submitted for Deployment',1,
                            'Document Deployed',2,
                 3) -- added this
```